# vue-dropzone doesn't generate thumbnails on file add

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dropzone.js

I wanna add files that are already on my Server to the Dropzone, I tried to search my problem over vue-dropzone Docs as well as the normal dropzone docs and I also went through like 5+ github issues and tried the help approaches there but I did not seem to find the solution.

So I call this method:

```
    this.product.images.forEach(image => {
      const file = { name: 'Icon', type: 'image/jpeg', dataURL: image };
      this.$refs.dropzone.manuallyAddFile(file, image);
    });
```

The files get added correctly but I simply get no Thumbnail generated at all. Thats basicly the whole problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can manually add thumbnail with `emit`:

```
this.product.images.forEach(image => {
      const file = { name: 'Icon', type: 'image/jpeg', dataURL: image };
      this.$refs.dropzone.manuallyAddFile(file, image);
      this.$refs.dropzone.dropzone.emit('thumbnail', file, file.dataURL)
      this.$refs.dropzone.dropzone.emit('complete', file)
    });
```

If your ref is `dropzone` you need to go to `this.$refs.dropzone.dropzone`.

And you need to call your method in `@vdropzone-mounted="loadPictures"`.

Good luck!

Comment: Oh, I am so dumb I saw this solution too but wasnt able to figure out how to use it with the vue-dropzone wrapper, so dropzone.dropzone it is, thanks a lot, the sizing is off but Im sure that I can solve that by myself (got it solved now with css class)

Comment: I founded somewhere option for sizing. If you want I can give it to you.

Comment: Thank you, I know that there is an option but it doesn´t seem to work on that trigger, a simple .dz-image class solved it, I just defined the size there too.

Comment: Cool. Yes just change class. Good luck, bye. :)

Comment: Oh and about the `@vdropzone-mounted` the problem why I do not use it is that my Database call is not finished yet so I do not have the Image URL´s and the mounted fires too early.